# Why can Direct3DCreate9 be slow?

Tags: directx, directx-9

I'm trying to speed up the start times for my Direct3D app a bit, and I have noticed Direct3DCreate9 takes a whole second according to profiler (more than anything else). Why? And what can be done about it?

OS: XP, DirectX: 9.0. Same behaviour on Windows 7 with different DirectX, and I have noticed many games suffer from this "Direct X initialization" lag too, so it's not like it's a problem with just my configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Direct3DCreate9` you're initializing all of the DirectX libraries.  This can take a while.

There is little you can do to improve the speed of this call.  The best option is to usually provide some visual feedback to the user that things are loading, if possible, while you first initialize DirectX.   This, at least, shows that your application is doing "something" and not just hung.

Comment: Still, I don't understand how initializing just a bunch of libraries can take one second. There are no DLLs being loaded while in Direct3DCreate9, in other words it's just executing code. I can hardly imagine any tasks which need this much time to compute.

Comment: @himself: Its not just initializing the libraries, but also doing checks against your graphics card, setting up caps for future calls, etc.. There's a lot that has to happen in order to initialize Direct3D, including talking to hardware.  There (unfortunately) isn't anything that can be done to improve the perf. there.  (Though it is much faster in release than debug D3D mode, btw...)